# Why In App Update is not working in release mode in my 3D Unity project?

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play, in-app-update

**Description:**

My game made with Unity (2022.3.12f1) is on Google Play Store and it has "In App Update" implemented.

**Problem:**

When i update my game on Play Store to a newer version, my older version do not shows the "NEW version available" pop-up. But if i play in a development .apk with a lower version than PlayStore i am being able to see the UPDATE pop-up

**Question:**

Why is it working only in development?

**My Code:**

This "InAppUpdate" script is attached to an Empty Game Object in the main scene.

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using Google.Play.AppUpdate;
using Google.Play.Common;

public class InAppUpdate : MonoBehaviour
{
    AppUpdateManager appUpdateManager;

    void Start()
    {
      appUpdateManager = new AppUpdateManager();
      StartCoroutine(CheckForUpdate());
    }

    IEnumerator CheckForUpdate()
    {
      PlayAsyncOperation<AppUpdateInfo, AppUpdateErrorCode> appUpdateInfoOperation = appUpdateManager.GetAppUpdateInfo();

      // Wait until the asynchronous operation completes.
      yield return appUpdateInfoOperation;

      if (appUpdateInfoOperation.IsSuccessful)
      {
        var appUpdateInfoResult = appUpdateInfoOperation.GetResult();
        // Creates an AppUpdateOptions defining an immediate in-app-update flow and its parameters.
        var appUpdateOptions = AppUpdateOptions.ImmediateAppUpdateOptions();

        StartCoroutine(StartImmediateUpdate(appUpdateInfoResult, appUpdateOptions));
      }
    }

    IEnumerator StartImmediateUpdate(AppUpdateInfo appUpdateInfoResult, AppUpdateOptions appUpdateOptions)
    {
      // Creates an AppUpdateRequest that can be used to monitor the
      // requested in-app update flow.
      var startUpdateRequest = appUpdateManager.StartUpdate(
        // The result returned by PlayAsyncOperation.GetResult().
        appUpdateInfoResult,
        // The AppUpdateOptions created defining the requested in-app update
        // and its parameters.
        appUpdateOptions);
      yield return startUpdateRequest;

      // If the update completes successfully, then the app restarts and this line
      // is never reached. If this line is reached, then handle the failure (for
      // example, by logging result.Error or by displaying a message to the user).
    }
}
```

**The error:**

> Exception: Field currentActivity or type signature  not found UnityEngine._AndroidJNIHelper.GetFieldID (System.IntPtr jclass, System.String fieldName, System.String signature, System.Boolean isStatic) (at :0) UnityEngine.AndroidJNIHelper.GetFieldID (System.IntPtr javaClass, System.String fieldName, System.String signature, System.Boolean isStatic) (at :0) UnityEngine._AndroidJNIHelper.GetFieldID[ReturnType] (System.IntPtr jclass, System.String fieldName, System.Boolean isStatic) (at :0) UnityEngine.AndroidJNIHelper.GetFieldID[FieldType] (System.IntPtr jclass, System.String fieldName, System.Boolean isStatic) (at :0) UnityEngine.AndroidJavaObject._GetStatic[FieldType] (System.String fieldName) (at :0) UnityEngine.AndroidJavaObject.GetStatic[FieldType] (System.String fieldName) (at :0) Google.Play.Common.UnityPlayerHelper.GetCurrentActivity () (at Assets/GooglePlayPlugins/com.google.play.common/Runtime/Scripts/UnityPlayerHelper.cs:32) Google.Play.AppUpdate.Internal.AppUpdateManagerPlayCore..ctor () (at Assets/GooglePlayPlugins/com.google.play.appupdate/Runtime/Scripts/Internal/AppUpdateManagerPlayCore.cs:34) Google.Play.AppUpdate.Internal.AppUpdateManagerInternal..ctor () (at Assets/GooglePlayPlugins/com.google.play.appupdate/Runtime/Scripts/Internal/AppUpdateManagerInternal.cs:35) Google.Play.AppUpdate.AppUpdateManager..ctor () (at Assets/GooglePlayPlugins/com.google.play.appupdate/Runtime/Scripts/AppUpdateManager.cs:33) InAppUpdate.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/InAppUpdate.cs:14)

I tried with my `InAppUpdate` script (Code shown above).